# How to prevent client from sending a message without user_id property in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

I have studied RabbitMQ documents but unfortunately I have not been able to solve following problems:

- How to restrict a user to read and write on specific queues.
- How to prevent client from sending a message without user_id property.

Answer (score 0):

> How to restrict a user to read and write on specific queues

Please carefully read [this document](https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html), specifically, [this section](https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html#permissions). Remember that messages are published to exchanges, so you have to limit "writing" by access control of the `basic.publish` method on an exchange via the `write` permission.

> How to prevent client from sending a message without user_id property

This is not possible without writing a custom plugin.